# TutrleBot2 installtion for kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!
I am new learner to ROS. I am using TurtleBot2 for learning purpose. But wen i visit ros website for installation of TurtleBot2, i found that it's not available for Kinetic. this is written on the website when I click on Kinetic version.

> Recently overhauled entire tutorial for indigo (24/03/15).

Then what should I do ? Do i need to install previous versions for ROS like Indigo  etc. Please guide me about this problem. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287156/tutrlebot2-installtion-for-kinetic/) by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-04-01**:
@Ibrahim_aerospace  Change some steps there only and it work fine
replace indigo with Kinetic

**Comment by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on 2018-04-01**:
thanks bro for reply. actually others packages can be installed but the problem is with two packages. it says unable to locate the package.
Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library
Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-04-01**:
@Ibrahim_aerospace may you post the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Full (re-)installation of turtlebot seems to work

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot*
```

---

Originally posted by [etorobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40302/etorobot/) with karma: 30 on 2019-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0